# Make Admin fieldset open by default when editing comment

Tags: 7, comments

As supplied by the core comment module when you go to edit a comment as an admin there is an Administration fieldset that lets you change the author and if the comment is published. When you load the page the fieldset is collapse and I'd like it to be open by default.

I found in the comments.module this bit of code:

```
// Display author information in a fieldset for comment moderators.
if ($is_admin) {
$form['author'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Administration'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => -2,
 );
}
```

Is there a hook or something I could use to manipulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hook_form_alter()`. Here's an example:

```
    function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'comment_node_YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_form') {
        $form['author']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
```

You can place this in a custom module, or in `template.php` of your your front end theme.